# python: How to find line with biggest number in it?

Tags: python, list, max

How to find line with  biggest number in file of lines that contains strings and numbers

```
def topSpeed(cars): 

y = raw_input("car type:")
with open("cars","r") as f:
    for l in f.readlines():
        list = []
        p = l.strip().split("|")
        type = p[1]
        max_speed = p[7]
        if y == type:
            list.append(l)
            a = 0
            for i in list:
                p = i.strip().split("|")
                max_speed = p[7]                    
                if max_speed > a:
                    a = max_speed
                    print(i)
                    pass 
                else:
                    print("...")    

        else:
            print("no cars of that type")
```

i tries this but it prints all cars of type thats input

and car list is:

```
a1|bmw|a|3.5|2.6|1.6|2018|150|3|5|x
a2|audi|a|2.50|1.60|4.50|2017|220|3|2|y
a3|audi|b|2.30|1.80|5.00|2011|180|4|4|x
a4|bmw|b|duz|vis|sir|god|230|3|5|y
```

Comment: We would need to see the "cars" file to be able to help you.

Comment: When you say "number" what does that mean? Integers `500`, floats `500.0`, fractions `500/1`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You problem is with the loop:

```
for i in list:
    p = i.strip().split("|")
    max_speed = p[7]                    
    if max_speed > a:
        a = max_speed
        print(i)
         pass 
    else:
        print("...")
```

This will print out "i" for every time max_speed > a so if your max speeds are in ascending order, it will print out every car. What you need to do is save the car with the with the max speed and then print it out at the end.

```
max_speed_car = ''
for i in list:
    p = i.strip().split("|")
    max_speed = p[7]                    
    if max_speed > a:
        a = max_speed
        max_speed_car = i
        pass 
    else:
        print("...")
print(max_speed_car)
```

something like that should do it. Here's the full code that worked on my computer just fine: (I'm running python 3.6)

```
def topSpeed(cars):
    y = input("car type:")
    with open(r"\cars.txt","r") as f:
            for l in f.readlines():
        list = []
        p = l.strip().split("|")
        type = p[1]
        max_speed = p[7]
        if y == type:
            list.append(l)
    a = 0
    max_speed_car = ''
    for i in list:
        p = i.strip().split("|")
        max_speed = int(p[7])                    
        if (max_speed > a):
            a = max_speed
            max_speed_car = i

        else:
            print("...")

    print(max_speed_car)
```

Comment: i tried this but it gives me error: "list" object is not callable

Comment: @louseDepo Try again. I fixed the print line

Comment: I tries again, but now it again prints "i" for every time max_speed > a

Comment: @louseDepo I added the whole code that I can run on my computer. This should solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the **speed** is always located in the seven position, you could try something like this:

```
with open('cars.txt') as infile:
    speed = max(infile.readlines(), key=lambda l: int(l.strip().split('|')[7]))
    print(speed)
```

**Output**

```
a4|bmw|b|duz|vis|sir|god|230|3|5|y
```

You can use the `key` parameter of the `max` function, in this case it says split the line by `'|'` and use the value in the seven position as key. These answer also assumes that the speed is an integer, as in your examples.